# PyTorch - CosineSimilarity in Sequential

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a model which consists of 3 parts:

- A submodule computing some vector `x`.
- A similar submodule computing some vector `y`.
- Final layer, which computes the similarity between these vectors and linearly scales it. Namely:

  ```
  self.final = nn.Sequential(
      nn.CosineSimilarity(),
      nn.Linear(1, 1),
  )
  ```

Now, I have problems with calling `self.final`. The following doesn't work:

- `self.final(x, y)`: `forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.
- `self.final([x, y])`: `forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x2'`.

How should I use `self.final`? Of course, I can apply `nn.CosineSimilarity` and `nn.Linear` separately, but I wonder how to make this module work.

**Edit:** after using the modules separately, it turns out that I also need to reshape the output of `CosineSimilarity`, with `.reshape(-1, 1)`, so the module as it is won't work. This also raises the question: how to fix the module (without defining a custom `Reshape` module like [this one](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-reshape-layer-in-pytorch/1110/7)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass multiple objects through a `torch.nn.Sequential` module. If you really want to understand what's going on under the hood consider looking at the [source:](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b7d5a0cf10f00e6380065122a866b7bde1298d5c/torch/nn/modules/container.py#L137). The `forward()` method of `Sequential` is implemented as

```
 def forward(self, input):
    for module in self:
        input = module(input)
    return input
```

(Also consider [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19808).)

So there is no way to do what you're asking with this module. But you can easily write your own, for instance following can accept multiple inputs to the *first* entry:

```
class MySeq(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def forward(self, *input):
        flag = True
        for module in self:
            if flag:
                input = module(*input)
                flag = False
            else:
                input = module(input)
        return input
```

To your second question: I don't think there are currently any modules in `torch.nn` for just reshaping. You need to do that manually, so I'd suggest writing your own module like:

```
class Final(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cs = nn.CosineSimilarity()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x, y):
        t = self.cs(x, y)
        return self.lin(t.reshape(-1, 1))
```